# unable to get cron script to work

Tags: linux, unix, heroku, cron

I run these three commands everyday:

```
cd /Users/xxx/code
heroku pgbackups:capture --expire
curl -o latest.dump `heroku pgbackups:url`
```

So I thought I'd try to move it into a cron job so I created a file called /Users/xxx/code/backup_script that has the following:

```
cd /Users/xxx/code
heroku pgbackups:capture --expire
curl -o latest.dump `heroku pgbackups:url`
```

However, when I run ./backup_script it gives this error:

```
./backup_script
./backup_script: line 2: heroku: command not found
./backup_script: line 3: heroku: command not found
curl: no URL specified!
curl: try 'curl --help' or 'curl --manual' for more information
```

I'm a unix newbie - can someone help me figure out how to fix the script above?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The environment variables for a cronjob are significantly reduced from your login; you'll want to set $PATH for your crontab.

For instance:

```
PATH=$HOME/bin:$PATH
@daily $HOME/backup_script
```

You may want to run `which heroku` to figure out what path you need to add.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a shebang telling it to use the bourne again shell (bash):

```
#!/bin/bash   
cd /Users/xxx/code
heroku pgbackups:capture --expire
curl -o latest.dump `heroku pgbackups:url`
```

A full path to heroku might help.

If you don't have luck here, you could also try the [Unix/Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) stack exchange site: